# Is there a way where I can output the duration of each test in Testcafe?

Tags: javascript, automated-tests, report, e2e-testing, testcafe

I have a testcafe suite with 6 tests inside. At the end of the Testcafe session it outputs the time of how long all the tests took together. What I'm wanting is to have the time for each test separately and the end the total as well.

I looked at this; https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/2217 but it looks like the reporter still outputs the total at the end?

For each test to show how long it took for the test to pass or failed

1. Test One (0m 13s)
2. Test Two (1m 15s)

2 passed (1m 28s)

Answer (score 3):

You will need to create a [custom reporter](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/extending-testcafe/reporter-plugin/) that outputs test results in the required format. Check out [this issue](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/2217) to find out how you can create one.

Comment: Yeah, I linked this earlier in my question and going through the reporter documentation it looks like it was still just outputting the total time? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Take a look at the [reportTestDone](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/extending-testcafe/reporter-plugin/reporter-methods.html#reporttestdone) method and its [testRunInfo](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/extending-testcafe/reporter-plugin/reporter-methods.html#testruninfo-object) parameter. There is `durationMs` property that indicates the duration of the test.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply; but I was able to find a custom reporter to do what I wanted to do! thanks!

Comment: @DjKniteX can you post a link to it or at least a name?

Comment: @DanielKaplan sorry for the late reply; but it was also posted below incase you missed it here's the link I used: https://www.npmjs.com/package/testcafe-reporter-time

Answer (score 1):

The most up to date and working plugin I've found so far is https://github.com/Raynos/testcafe-reporter-spec-time.

[image: screenshot of log from testcafe-reporter-spec-time]

Comment: Oh, I see. Seems to be issue opened about it: https://github.com/Raynos/testcafe-reporter-spec-time/issues/1

Answer (score 0):

You can install this reporter plug in: https://www.npmjs.com/package/testcafe-reporter-time

Here are instructions for installing and using it: https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/guides/concepts/reporters.html#use-the-reporters

### Install the Reporters

You can install reporter packages from npm as you would install any other plugin. See Install Plugins.

### Use the Reporters

When running tests, you can select a reporter to generate test reports. You can do this by using the -r (--reporter) command line option or the runner.reporter API method.